# postgres connection through VBA

Tags: vba, postgresql, amazon-web-services, adodb

I have a bunch of macros that currently connect to our "local" oracle machines but our company is going through AWS migration and now I will need to adjust my connections to connect to the new database.  This is my current function to connect to Oracle:

```vb
Function query_DB(dataSource As String, strSQL As String, Optional serverName As String, Optional orcl As String, Optional UN As String, Optional PW As String) As ADODB.Recordset
Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection, cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim oRS As New ADODB.Recordset, userName As String, passWord As String
Set query_DB = New ADODB.Recordset

If UN = "" Then
    userName = "test"
Else
    userName = UN
End If
If PW = "" Then
    passWord = "test"
Else
    passWord = PW
End If


strSQL = convOrcl(strSQL, serverName)


    tmpds = Split(dataSource, ",")
    tmporcl = Split(orcl, ".")

    With oConn
        .Provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle"
        .Properties("Data Source") = UCase(tmporcl(0))
        .Properties("User id") = userName
        .Properties("Password") = passWord
    .Open
    End With


On Error Resume Next
query_DB.Open strSQL, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

End Function
```

Only real input value is the oraclename in the function above.

Could someone help me modify this function so that it'll work with postgres?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your project is using a reference to MS ActiveX Data Objects (`ADODB.*`).
Postgresql does not come with ODBC driver in the standard installation, you'll need to download it [here](https://odbc.postgresql.org/).

Once this is done, I suggest you try to set the `ConnectionString` property of your `oConn` object to one of the values provided on [that site](https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql-odbc-driver-psqlodbc/).